# how to rewrite url for htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to rewrite a url:

```
http://www.foo.it/abc.php
```

become

```
http://www.foo.it/abc
```

So I want to eliminate php exstension.how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w\d\-]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```